# Once my functions are nested and reference eachother, my tuples return NoneType errors, why?

Tags: python, dictionary, tuples, key, nonetype

I wrote functions to call and replace tuples from a dictionary. The functions all work independently. When I run them individually the tuple values return integers as planned. When run in sequence or nested with other functions, the tuples return NoneType error. When I run type on my called tuple it returns integer. I'm confused and wanted to solve this issue before I convert to a class structure to tidy up.

My current workflow is: takes in an integer determined from previous code (volume)> conditionally chooses a divisor> rounds down the value> matches the value in a dictionary> returns the value from the dictionary> new tuple created> tuple in dictionary is replaced

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-23-1f1ae48bdda3> in <module>
----> 1 asp_master(275,dict_tuberack1,vol_tuberack1,tuberack1,'A1')
      2 height_a1= get_height(dict_tuberack1,tuberack1,'A1')
      3 asp_a(275,height_a1,tuberack1['A1'])
      4 disp_master(275,dict_tuberack1,vol_tuberack1,tuberack1,'A2')
      5 height_a2= get_height(dict_tuberack1,tuberack1,'A2')

<ipython-input-10-ba8bc2194a15> in asp_master(volume, dict_vol, dict_labware, labware, well)
      1 def asp_master(volume,dict_vol,dict_labware,labware,well):
----> 2     if low_vol_check(volume,dict_labware,labware,well)==True:
      3         new_vol=volume_sub(volume,dict_labware,labware,well)
      4         tup_update_sub(new_vol,dict_vol,dict_labware,labware,well)
      5         print(dict_labware[labware[well]])

<ipython-input-16-a23165d51020> in low_vol_check(volume, dict_labware, labware, well)
     10 
     11 def low_vol_check(volume,dict_labware,labware,well):
---> 12     x=get_volume(dict_labware,labware,well)
     13     y=volume
     14     if  x-y < 0:

<ipython-input-16-a23165d51020> in get_volume(dict_labware, labware, well)
      1 def get_volume(dict_labware,labware,well):
      2     tup = dict_labware.get(labware[well])
----> 3     (tup_v,tup_h)=tup
      4     volume=tup_v
      5     return tup_v

TypeError: cannot unpack non-iterable NoneType object
```

Robot Code:

```
from opentrons import protocol_api
from opentrons.simulate import get_protocol_api
from math import floor,ceil
from datetime import datetime
import opentrons

protocol = get_protocol_api('2.8')

tuberack1 = protocol.load_labware('opentrons_15_tuberack_nest_15ml_conical','2', 'tuberack1')
tuberack2 = protocol.load_labware('opentrons_24_tuberack_nest_1.5ml_snapcap','3','tuberack2')
tiprack= protocol.load_labware('opentrons_96_tiprack_300ul','4')
p300 = protocol.load_instrument('p300_single', 'left', tip_racks=[tiprack])
p300.home
```

Code:

```
dict_tuberack1={tuberack1['A1']:(14000,104), tuberack1['A2']:(14000,104), tuberack1['A3']:(14000,104),}
vol_tuberack1= {14000: 104, 13500: 101, 13000: 98, 12500: 94, 
                12000: 91, 11500: 88, 11000: 85, 10500: 81, 
                10000: 78, 9500: 75, 9000: 72, 8500: 68, 
                8000: 65, 7500: 62, 7000: 59, 6500: 55, 
                6000: 52, 5500: 49,}

def get_volume(dict_labware,labware,well):
    tup = dict_labware.get(labware[well])
    (tup_v,tup_h)=tup
    volume=tup_v
    return tup_v

def low_vol_check(volume,dict_labware,labware,well):
    x=get_volume(dict_labware,labware,well)
    y=volume
    if  x-y < 0:
        return False
    else:
        return True
def tup_update_sub(volume,dict_vol,dict_labware,labware,well):
    tup = dict_labware.get(labware[well])
    adj_list=list(tup)
    adj_list[0]=volume
    divisor=1
    if volume >=1000:
        divisor=1000
        vol_even=round_down(volume, divisor)
    elif 100 <= volume <1000: #this was the issue and was fixed.
        divisor=100
        vol_even=round_down(volume,divisor)
    else:
        divisor=10
        vol_even=round_down(volume,divisor)    

    new_height=dict_vol.get(vol_even)
    adj_list[1]=new_height

    new_tup=tuple(adj_list)
    dict_labware[labware[well]] = new_tup

def asp_master(volume,dict_vol,dict_labware,labware,well):
    if low_vol_check(volume,dict_labware,labware,well)==True:
        new_vol=volume_sub(volume,dict_labware,labware,well)
        tup_update_sub(new_vol,dict_vol,dict_labware,labware,well)
        print(dict_labware[labware[well]])
    else:
        print('Cannot aspirate')  

#robot commands below
def asp_a (volume,height,source):
    p300.pick_up_tip()
    p300.aspirate(volume, source.bottom(z=height))

def disp_a (volume,height,destination):
    p300.dispense(volume,destination.bottom(z=height+8))
    p300.blowout(height+8)

#code that generated error message below
asp_master(275,dict_tuberack1,vol_tuberack1,tuberack1,'A1')
height_a1= get_height(dict_tuberack1,tuberack1,'A1')
asp_a(275,height_a1,tuberack1['A1'])
```

Comment: You can't call `asp_a` and `disp_a` before they're defined.

Comment: Where is the definition of `tuberack1`?

Comment: If the key `labware[well]` isn't found in `dict_labware`, `tup` will be `None`. It would probably be better to use `dict_labware[labware[well]]` so you get that error immediately.

Comment: @Barmar reformatted, but no code changed. The theory is that the code is looking up the correct placeholder for the value via dict_tuberack1, then updating it with a new tuple that is referenced from the vol_tuberack dictionary

Comment: I think you have the arguments to `asp_master()` in the wrong order. `vol_tuberack1` should be the 2nd argument.

Comment: @Barmar you have solved a truly embarrassing problem. Thanks again for your help. The arguments were switched!